# Setting the default profile in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I have two Thunderbird profiles, and my `profiles.ini` looks like this:

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=e17id64t.default

[Profile1]
Name=custom
IsRelative=1
Path=l48ojhgn.custom
Default=1
```

`Profile1` is marked as default, but that is only because it was started last. If I start `Profile0`, it will became the default instead.

How can I set `Profile0` to be always the default profile, regardless of which profile was started as last time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main concern is which profile will be used when `mailto` link is clicked, then the solution is to always start the default profile normally and launch all other profiles with the `-no-remote` option.

The way it works is that if you start a profile with the `-no-remote` option, firefox does not see it that it is running. Firefox will only see the default instance (which was started without `-no-remote`)

This is all explained in this [MozzilaZine Article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile)

Comment: that seems to work OK

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can only change the `StartsWithLastProfile=1` to make Thunderbird ask every time it starts up.

That is obviously not what you want so you will have to provide the `-P default` option when starting Thunderbird.

On my system `$(which thunderbird)` gives `/usr/bin/thunderbird` which itself is a link to `../lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh`. You can replace the link with a small executable script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird.sh -P default $*
```

and your profile with `Name=default` is always started, either from the commandline, or by opening via the GUI (as that should just call this executable `thunderbird`).

I am not sure what Thunderbird does when you specify multiple profiles on the commandline and run this **script** with `thunderbird -P custom`. If it still takes the `default` profile, you may want to move the `$*` in the script to before the `-P`.

Comment: what I mostly care about, is that when I click an `mailto` link, that always `Profile0` will be used (to open the compose window).

Comment: @user1968963 - to do that you'll want to change the last line of `/usr/bin/thunderbird` as Anthon has described s othat it's `exec $MOZ_LAUNCHER $script_args $MOZ_PROGRAM -P default`. You could also move the original `thunderbird` script out of the way (change its name to `thunderbird.orig`, and then make Anthons script `/usr/lib/thunderbird` and have it call the `thunderbird.orig` script.